# Substitute for C# SignedXml in PHP

Tags: c#, php, windows-store-apps, signedxml

I am trying to verify IAP receipt sent for Windows Store. The code sample to verify receipt in C# is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx). I am trying to validate the receipt using PHP but not able to validate it. I am trying openssl but it is always returning 0. Is there any substitute of C# SignedXml class in PHP?

Thanks